# How to design a binary up down counter using D flip flop's and the 'up' or 'down' count will be controlled by another flip flop?

Tags: flipflop, counter

I have to design a 4bit Binary Up Down counter using D flip-flops .  But here is the catch I cannot directly use a switch to control whether the counter will count up or down, I have to do that using a D flip flop. Any help on how I can solve this?

N.B. I can design an up down counter , but I need to know how to use another D flip flop to control the whether I want up or down count

Comment: Do you know how to design the up or down counter alone?

Comment: yes I do , I just need to know how to use the D flip flop as a switch

Comment: What will control the d type that you want to function as a switch?

Comment: I need help on how to implement the new d flip flop into the circuit, I am not getting any clue on how to use this new flip flop :/

Comment: Until you know what "thing" or "action" sets up or down counting, you cannot proceed.

Comment: Seems like you are just using the new ff to hold the decision to count up or down.  Attach your switch to the set and reset pins of the new flop. Use the outputs to change your up/down logic.

Comment: This smells like a **big** [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what "using a D flip flop" means, I can provide at least two approaches.

First, instead of a single switch, you can provide two - an up/down switch and a "load control" switch. Using an NO switch operating on the open-to-close action for the control switch can be done by

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDqHVn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But keep in mind that I have provided no debouncing on the clock switch, which you must provide.

Alternatively, if you want the control FF driven by the same clock which drives the counter, you can do it but you have to delay the clock between the control FF and the counter in order to allow a change in the control input to settle before the counter acts on it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZzMhK.png)</sup>

Note that a pair of inverters makes a perfectly usable delay, and multiple pairs of inverters make for longer delays.